# Why are all LL(1) grammars LR(1)?

Tags: theory, grammar, proof, lr-grammar, ll-grammar

It's a widely-known fact that any LL(1) grammar is also LR(1), but I can't seem to find a rigorous proof of this anywhere.  I've heard some high-level overviews of the proof (for example, that since an LL(1) grammar has its productions determined from just one token at a time while LR(1) grammars can have much more input scanned before a decision is made).  However, after consulting two textbooks on compilers and parsing and doing a quick Google search, I can't seem to track down a more formal proof of this fact.

Does anyone know this proof, or at least where to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A paper discussing this can be found at http://doc.utwente.nl/66947/1/ipl-2_1982.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  I actually found this paper about an hour ago and was going to post it myself, but I couldn't find a public link to it.